# Why is the 'time ago' not displayed in my view?

Tags: view, drupal-7, block, dashboard

I'm not sure whether this is a bug or not, so I'm just going to ask this. I created a view (and block) with a 'Comment: Post date' field with 'Time ago (with "ago" appended)' as Date format. I didn't fill in a custom date format.

Everything is previewed perfectly, but when I go to my dashboard, I only see the "ago": the actual numbers (hours, minutes, seconds...) aren't displayed.

I cleared caches, but nothing happened. I'm still using the default Seven 7.23 administration theme for my dashboard and I didn't set a custom template file or anything else. I just created the view.

How can I solve this?

**Edit**: I exported my view, so you can read the code [here](http://drupaltesting.weebly.com/time-ago.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what causes the problem, but I solved it temporally. I changed the Date format to 'Time ago' an added the 'ago' manually via the 'Rewrite results' function.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your cache in drupal. Admin > Configuration > Performance > Clear All Caches

(/admin/config/development/performance)

I noticed you said you added Comment: Post Date. If you did not mean to display the time of comments on the node then my guess is that would be your issue. If not comments exist, you have nothing to get the last time.

If you wanted to get the last time of the save for the node then you will need to switch to last updated to fix your issue.

**Edit:** It seems odd to me that everything is working in the views preview section but not on the actual page. This leads me to think it might have something to do with the user you are viewing it with. Are you logged in when you test it, or are you opening it in a different browser on a new session? Check the user permissions for your content field type and make sure "can view" is checked.

Comment: The 'Comment: Post Date' is exactly what I need. I updated my question to give you some more information.

Comment: I'm logged in as user-1 (administrator), so I can do and see everything that's possible. I'm always working in Firefox 23.0.